# SQL Server: is it possible to get recently inserted identity column value without table variable

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have a table

```
my_table(id int identity(1,1) not null primary key, data varchar(100))
```

I want to write a procedure that inserts a new row into that table and returns id.
I tried

```
DECLARE @new_id INT;    
SELECT @new_id = id FROM
(
INSERT INTO my_table(data) OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES ('test') 
) as NewVal(id)
```

That code doesn't work (I got "A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows for an INSERT statement."). However, if I use a table variable, I can do

```
DECLARE @new_id INT;    
DECLARE @tmp_table TABLE(int id);
INSERT INTO @tmp_table
SELECT id FROM
(
INSERT INTO my_table(data) OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES ('test')  
) as NewVal(id);
// OR 
INSERT INTO my_table(data) OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @tmp_table VALUES ('test') ;
SELECT @new_id = id FROM @tmp_table;
```

Is it possible to achieve the same functionality without using table variable ?

**UPDATE**
Thanks for quick responses, +1 to everyone for solution with SCOPE_IDENTITY.
That's probably my fault, I should have asked the question clearly  - I do use `MERGE` (an example would be much longer, so I posted `INSERT` instead) , not `INSERT` so SCOPE_IDENTITY doesn't really work for me.

Comment: But if you're using a MERGE statement, chances are probably quite high you're not updating/inserting a single row - in that case, you would **definitely** need a table variable to hold all new identities, no?? And even if you should have a single new identity - I don't see any harm in having a table variable, and using the `OUTPUT Inserted.ID INTO @tablevar` - why do you want to avoid this like the devil??

Comment: @marc_s: Mostly for curiosity. For instance, `SELECT @var1= field1 FROM table1` is a valid query, and I thought I could do something similar for `merge` +`output` .  In my particular case I did a single row update/insert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit shorter version than nesting in a insert statement is using `output...into`.

```
declare @tmp_table table(actiontaken nvarchar(10), id int);

merge my_table
using (values ('test')) as S(data)
on 0=1
when not matched then 
  insert (data) values (S.data)
output $action, inserted.id into @tmp_table;
```

I do believe that you should use a table variable from the merge. The output may contain more than one row.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can just return [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) after the insert (this is safer than @@IDENTITY due to the scoping differences).

i.e.

```
INSERT my_table (data) VALUES ('test')
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`  will get the last inserted identity value in the scope.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3):

If you use

```
select @@identity
```

you will get the last value entered into the identity column from anywhere.

If you want the value entered into the column from the script that just ran, you should use

```
select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

If you just want the last value inserted into the identity column for a given table from any statement in any session, you should use

```
select IDENT_CURRENT('tablename')
```

Answer (score 1):

`select @@identity` or `select SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will return the value you're looking for